# NLTK. Punkt not found

Tags: python, django, nginx, nltk, gunicorn

As the title suggests, punkt isn't found.
Of course, I've already `import nltk` and `nltk.download('all')`.

This still doesn't solve anything and I'm still getting this error:

> Exception Type:    LookupError
>   Exception Value:
>   NLTK tokenizers are missing. Download them by following command: python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')"

I ran nltk.data.path and it output

```
['/root/nltk_data', '/usr/nltk_data', '/usr/share/nltk_data', '/usr/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/share/nltk_data', '/usr/local/share/nltk_data', '/usr/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data']
```

punkit is under `/root/nltk_data` and I've already checked file permissions.

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the user didn't have permission to access the file.

Answer here:
[different nltk results in django and at command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608189/different-nltk-results-in-django-and-at-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Which module have you tried to import from nltk?
After importing nltk try to download that module alone using nltk.download('module' )..

Comment: [nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!

Comment: Try using below ```import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

from nltk import word_tokenize```.. Also go thru https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867197/failed-loading-english-pickle-with-nltk-data-load